# How do I avoid outputting duplicate matches in a function?

Tags: c++, duplicates

I have a program that reads in two text files, one with job candidates and the other with open positions, and puts them each into an array. They share one data point in common - 'position'.

One of the functions within the program checks for and prints all matches. The problem I have is if I have multiple openings with the same position, it will output the same candidate multiple times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>  
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void FindMatches(string candidates[][6], int cand_size, string openings[][7], int opening_size)
{
    cout <<setw(15) <<"F. NAME:" <<setw(15) <<"L. NAME" <<setw(15)<< "POSITION" <<setw(15)<<"SALARY" << setw(15)
    << "RATING" << setw(15) << "PHO. #"<< endl << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<opening_size; i++)
    {
        string openingHolder = openings[i][1]; ///placeholder variable for position that matches are being searched for
        for(int j=0; j<cand_size; j++)
        {
            if(candidates[j][2] == openingHolder)
                {
                for(int k=0; k<6; k++)
                    cout<<setw(15)<<left<<candidates[j][k];
                cout << endl;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR5UC.png)

I've tried introducing break and continue statements in the loops at different places but they all either do nothing or totally break everything. I tried creating a duplicateChecker array to hold every match in and compare new matches against but I got lost at this point and reverted back to the original function I had written.

Comment: Your usage of 2-dimensional arrays is confusing.  What is the significance of `openings[i][1];`?  Why is `candidates[j][2]` a special case?  The easy way to check for duplicates is throw everything of one array into `std::set<string>` and that's it, since a `std::set` does not store duplicates, thus no need to check.  If not that, I am sure a simple usage of an STL algorithm function such as `std::set_intersection` along with `std::sort` can be done.  Whichever way, that would be way better than writing buggy hand-coded `for` loops.

Comment: Also, this would be much simpler if you used a [struct instead of parallel arrays to describe each candidate](https://godbolt.org/z/h31vs9MWM)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I agree completely, and if I were writing the program from scratch I would absolutely use structs, but the assignment involved us being given a pre-written program with several blank functions to fill in and make it work.

I'll take a look at sets. I've never worked with that before but it seems like it's important and a way to get at what I'm trying to do.

openings[i][1] is the "position" in each line of the openings array. candidates[j][2] is the "position" in each line of the candidates array. The output shows all the components of the candidates array, may clear it up.

Answer (score -1):

You just need a check to keep track of positions already processed. maybe something like this

```
set<string> posProcessed;

for (int i = 0; i < opening_size; i++)
{
     string openingHolder = openings[i][1]; ///placeholder variable for position that matches are being searched for

    if (posProcessed.find(openingHolder) == posProcessed.end())
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cand_size; j++)
        {
            if (candidates[j][2] == openingHolder)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)
                    cout << setw(15) << left << candidates[j][k];
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
        posProcessed.insert(openingHolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything. Added the set library and it compiled but it still has the duplicates :/

Comment: Please explain to @MichaelWerle what the purpose of `std::set` is.  Maybe explaining why you used `std::set` would be more helpful in this answer.

Comment: std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key. 
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

A set doesn't allow duplicates. When you add a position to the set, it automatically ensures that duplicates are not stored. This ensures that you don't process the same position multiple times